# I want to display an icon or message on a different webpage whenever an ajax page is actively refreshing original webpage. Can this be done?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a webpage (index.php)that is using ajax to refresh a php page (dbcheck.php) which is pulling data from a mysql DB and displaying it. The ajax is refreshing the script(dbcheck.php) every second so its almost in real time.  I want to display an icon or message on a third webpage, on the same server, whenever the ajax page is actively refreshing so I know the page is active.(someone is on the page) Can I add a second ajax POST to index.php that POSTS to the 3rd page or ? Does anyone have any ideas how this could be achieved?

```
index.php:

<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {  
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false 
}); 

var rowdisplayvalue = "<?php echo $rowdisplayvalue; ?>";//row display variable passed through   
setInterval(function() {

$('#divToRefresh').load('dbcheck.php', {rowdisplayvalue: rowdisplayvalue});
}, 1000); // refers to the time to refresh the div.in milliseconds.
});

// ]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't post to a page, you can only post from a page. Use comet (long polling Ajax) or web sockets to read the event in the other session. You need some mechanism of recording the event triggered by monitored session for this to be readable by the monitoring session.